# Selecting a specific sheet in VSTO Excel Add-In

Tags: c#, vsto

I'm trying to select a specific sheet (by name or index) with my excel Add-In with no avail.

My addin file `ThisAddIn.cs` has:

```
public Excel.Workbook GetActiveWorkbook()
{
    return (Excel.Workbook)Application.ActiveWorkbook;
}
```

And my `Ribbon1.cs` has:

```
namespace Test3
{
    public partial class Ribbon1
    {
        private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Hello");
            Workbook currentwb = Globals.ThisAddIn.GetActiveWorkbook();
            Worksheet scratch = currentwb.Worksheets.Item[1] as Worksheet; // Error blocks here
            if (scratch == null)
                return;
            // Worksheet scratch = currentwb.Worksheets["Sheets1"];
            scratch.Range["A1"].Value = "Hello";
        }
    }
}
```

But I get a `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

I'm new to c# (come from Python) and am very confused why this doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you check that the worksheet exist ? (via currentwb.Worksheets.Count ) before to access it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I was trying to load the `Workbook` instance before it was loaded. In other words, trying to grab the instance in `Ribbon Load` was too early. Grabbing the instance on a `ButtonClick` event worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Excel.Application ExApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application as Excel.Application;

            Worksheet sheet = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(ExApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[1]);
            Worksheet vsheet = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(ExApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[2]);

            sheet.Cells[1, 1] = "A1";
vsheet.Cells[1, 1] = "A1 from second sheet";
```

Comment: The question was already answered by the asker, he found his problem.